# I need help in resolving the error where the

Tags: c#

Here, I am trying to write a program which receives input values from the text file and assigns the values to the appropriate variables. But I am facing errors like:

> System.Collections.Generic.List' does not
>   contain a definition for 'length' and no extension method 'length'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' could
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

The same errors even for height,depth volume.Kindly resolve this error.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace ReadInputDetails
{
    class Boxdetails
    {
        private string boxno;
        private double length;
        private double height;
        private double depth;
        private double volume;

        // Declare a number of box of type string:
        public string box_no
        {
            get 
            {
               return boxno; 
            }
            set 
            {
               boxno = value; 
            }
        }

        // Declare  properties of box of type double:
        public double box_length
        {
            get 
            { 
               return length; 
            }
            set 
            { 
               length = value; 
            }
        }
        public double box_height
        {
            get
            {
                return height;
            }
            set
            {
                height = value;
            }
        }
        public double box_depth
        {
            get
            {
                return depth;
            }
            set
            {
                depth = value;
            }
        }
        public double box_volume
        {
            get
            {
                return volume;
            }
            set
            {
                volume = value;
            }
        }

            public static void getdetailsofbox(string[] args)
            {
                try
                {
                    List<Boxdetails> box = new List<Boxdetails>();

                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:/containervalues.txt"))
                    {
                        string line;

                        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            // create new instance of container for each line in file
                            Boxdetails b = new Boxdetails();
                            string[] Parts = line.Split(' ');
                            // set non-static properties of container
                            box.boxno = Parts[0];
                            box.length = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[1]);
                            box.height = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[2]);
                            box.depth = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[3]);
                            box.volume = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[4]);
                            // add container to list of containers
                            b.Add(box);
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // what failed?
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: First of all, your properties naming is just ugly. Second, you want to call `b.box_no`, `b.box_length` and so forth.

Comment: You should really name you variables better. Calling a list of box details a box is silly and it even confused yourself. You should name the list something like `listOfBoxes` or just `boxes` and name a single box `box`. Had you done that, you most likely wouldn't have confused the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're assigning values to the list, not the `box` object. Change:

```
Boxdetails b = new Boxdetails();
string[] Parts = line.Split(' ');
// set non-static properties of container
box.boxno = Parts[0];
box.length = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[1]);
box.height = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[2]);
box.depth = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[3]);
box.volume = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[4]);
// add container to list of containers
b.Add(box);
```

To:

```
Boxdetails b = new Boxdetails();
string[] Parts = line.Split(' ');
// set non-static properties of container
b.box_no = Parts[0];
b.box_length = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[1]);
b.box_height = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[2]);
b.box_depth = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[3]);
b.box_volume = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[4]);
// add container to list of containers
box.Add(b);
```

Also, consider naming the list of boxes something like `listOfBoxes` or just `boxes` and rename the `BoxDetails` class to just `Box` as it represents a box. Then you could write `boxes.add(box);` which would make more sense, don't you agree?

On a side note: there's a thing called [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) (and also [coding conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx)) that you might want to adhere to.

Comment: I agree with u.. but i am still learning c#. Hope i will do better.. Thank u .

Comment: @user3227279 We've all been beginners at some time. If my answer solved your problem please consider accepting it.